# Change media image directory path

Tags: product-images, media

I know it's not recommended but I want to upload product images to any folder in my web server's root directory instead of magento's media folder.

```
<upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">sales/store/logo</upload_dir>
```

The base image upload path is set with the config attribute (system/filesystem/media above).
I've updated system config value Base Media URL to `http::/127.0.0.1/external`.
But I don't see my product images being saved in `http::/127.0.0.1/external` folder once image is uploaded and product is saved.

Can anyone share where is the actual upload image code present? I've checked in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media::addImage()` by doing Mage::log() but I think this function is not being called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to symlink the media directory or the corresponding subfolder to another location on disk:

`ln -s media/catalog/product/ /mnt/my/huge/fileserver/location`

Comment: good trick @philwinkle

Answer (score 0):

If your environment is chrooted this solution won't work well.

As the apache / nginx process and php-fpm will view paths as absolute, but your CLI will not be able to see the second path in /mnt thus giving some issues.

An alternative would be a bind mount

In your `/etc/fstab` you can use

```
/mnt/md3/<my_storage>/pub/media /<path_to_docroot>/pub/media none bind,user=<magento_owner> 0 0
```

This has a downside if your system relies on `df` to calculate disk size because the disk size will be appearing as the normal partitions size + the bind mount's size. You will be able to utilize the full space, just `df` will display wrong sizes and it can have potential issues in backup applications, elastic search (if it's hosted in the same server using the same partition)

I'm still looking for a better alternative myself