# Move pub/media/catalog and /downloadable files to another server?

Tags: magento2, downloadable, media, filesystem

Is it possible, with Magento 2 to move product images and downloadables files (attached to downloadable products type, and sold) to another server and keep things still working ?

I'm not talking about AWS or other similar clouds but just a regular linux filesystem on another server.

Anyone already achieved this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes both are certainly possible with Magento 2, where you host your static assets like images and downloadable files on a different server (or even from a different domain from the same server).

You need to change Base URL for the user media files to your external domain

as well as need to change your CORS policy in your web server.

Check these SE threads below to get you in a right direction

[Is it possible to serve images from Magento 2 using a URL reference?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217015/is-it-possible-to-serve-images-from-magento-2-using-a-url-reference)

[Magento Store product image another domain?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46298/magento-store-product-image-another-domain)

[How to manage Downloadable Product storage location in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166605/how-to-manage-downloadable-product-storage-location-in-magento)

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23339

[Change media image directory path](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92084/change-media-image-directory-path)

Comment: I will get a try with the last link you provide : seems simple :) ```ln -s media/catalog/product/ /mnt/my/huge/fileserver/location``` thanks for the research !

Answer (score 0):

You may need to regenerate your images cache as the new server may not generate the right links to the images (you'll see immediately when you browse your shop as there won't be any product images). In that case delete the cache and run the following command:

> php bin/magento catalog:image:resize

Note this can take a long time!